# How to set up Let's Encrypt with Azure? Trying to get SSL for my custom domain app service

Tags: azure, ssl, lets-encrypt

I've tried following this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6V_mBo-gnE

But the setup has changed, because you need some more properties now:
[image]

see more here: https://www.poppastring.com/blog/azure-lets-encrypt-dashboardconnectionstring-field-is-required

The property names does not fit the names in Azure either, so more confusion for me.

Is it possible to just do this from the certify client? I managed to do this for Godaddy, but the DNS Update Method "Azure DNS API" is also confusing..

Sorry I can only find old guides for this..

Answer (score 0):

Both of these should be set to your Azure Storage Account connection string, e.g. `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[myaccount];AccountKey=[mykey];`

Please see Scott's post here for complete instructions on using the Let's encrypt extension with Azure Web Apps.:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/securing-an-azure-app-service-website-under-ssl-in-minutes-with-lets-encrypt